# Complex Tori projection question

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is based on Miranda's *"Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces"*; at page 9, it is stated that, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we define the parallelogram
$$
P_z=\left\{z+\lambda_1 w_1 + \lambda_2 w_2;\lambda_i\in\left[ 0,1\right]\right\}
$$
This definition uses two linearly independent complex numbers (LI over $\mathbb{R}$) $w_1$ and $w_2$ to define the lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}w_1+\mathbb{Z}w_2$; the torus is obtained as the quotient group $X=\mathbb{C}/L$.

It is stated:
*Note that any point of $\mathbb{C}$ is congruent modulo L to a point of $P_z$.*

How can this be true no matter what $\lambda_i$ I consider in $\left[ 0,1 \right]$?

Comment: There is a projection map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/L.$

Comment: Yes, but this shows that any point of $\mathbb{C}$ is congruent to a point of $\mathbb{C}/L$, not to a point of $P_z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$, they span $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over $\Bbb R$.  So, given any $\hat z\in \Bbb C$, you can write ${\hat z}-z$ as $\mu_1 w_1 + \mu_2 w_2$ for some real numbers $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.  Write each of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ as the sum of an integer and a fractional part,
$$\mu_1 = i_1 + \lambda_1, \ \ \mu_2 = i_2 + \lambda_2, \qquad  i_1, i_2\in{\Bbb Z},\ \ \  \lambda_1, \lambda_2\in[0,1).$$
Now if you set $$p:=z+\lambda_1 w_1 + \lambda_2 w_2\in P_z$$
and 
$$q:=i_1 w_1 + i_2 w_2\in L,$$
then
$$\hat z = z+\mu_1 w_1 + \mu_2 w_2 = z + (i_1+\lambda_1) w_1 + (i_2+\lambda_2 ) w_2=p+q.$$
Therefore, $\hat z$ is the sum of $p$ and $q$, so it is congruent modulo $L$ to the element $p$ of $P_z$.

Comment: I need it in $P_z$, not in $L$.

Comment: ooohhh Ok, thanks! :)